# How to use create table and drop table DDL statements in stored proc in oracle.

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

Ihave created a proc like this

```
create or replace PROCEDURE RMD_Tables  AS
Begin

execute immediate 'Drop table a608232_new_62K_master';

execute immediate 'create table a608232_new_62K_master as select A.* from 
a608232_MRD_DATA_62K_W_Account A inner join a608232_new_mids B
on A.MID = B.MID';

execute immediate'drop table a608232_web_abt_qlik_data';

execute immediate 'create table a608232_web_abt_qlik_data as select 
lv2.IP,SESSION_ID,PAGENAME,VSCHANNEL,VSSEARCHPHRASE,click_date,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM click_date)"YEAR",EXTRACT(MONTH FROM 
click_date)"MONTH",EXTRACT(DAY FROM 
click_date)"DAY",wb.CLICK_HR,wb.CLICK_MIN,
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY SESSION_ID ORDER BY SESSION_CLK_SEQ_NBR ASC)  
SESSION_RANK
from abc  wb
right outer join A608232.a608232_new_62K_master  lv2 on wb.IP = lv2.IP WHERE  
click_date >= TO_DATE(''25-SEP-2017'',''DD-MON-YYYY'') AND 
vschannel=''aaaa'' ' ;

END;
```

When I execute this procedure my first table is getting dropped/ After that I am getting this error msg

```
Connecting to the database CWE_Nexedia.
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "A608232.RMD_TABLES", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 2
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database CWE_Nexedia.
```

My first statement is getting executed after that i am facing issue. 
I am doing this becoz I want to schedule a job that will run everyday to update these tables.

Comment: What is your interpretation of the message, `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`?  Also, why don't you simply replace the contents of the table instead of dropping and creating it?

Comment: @DanBracuk I have the previledges when i run it sepately i can run and create it. The replace option how do you suggest i do that

Comment: To replace the contents, use two queries.  The first will be a delete and the second will be an insert.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I suggest to use [`q'{}'`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i42617) to avoid duplicating `''` for instance:

```
execute immediate q'{create table a608232_web_abt_qlik_data as select 
lv2.IP,SESSION_ID,PAGENAME,VSCHANNEL,VSSEARCHPHRASE,click_date,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM click_date)"YEAR",EXTRACT(MONTH FROM 
click_date)"MONTH",EXTRACT(DAY FROM 
click_date)"DAY",wb.CLICK_HR,wb.CLICK_MIN,
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY SESSION_ID ORDER BY SESSION_CLK_SEQ_NBR ASC)  
SESSION_RANK
from abc  wb
right outer join A608232.a608232_new_62K_master  lv2 on wb.IP = lv2.IP WHERE  
click_date >= TO_DATE('25-SEP-2017','DD-MON-YYYY') AND 
vschannel='aaaa' }' ;
```

Second:

> insufficient privileges

It is pretty clear error message. You have to make sure you have priviliges to `CREATE TABLE` and read from specific tables.

---

You could also consider other options:

- TRUNCATE TABLE and INSERT INTO
- create materialized view and refresh it on daily basis

**EDIT:**

> I have the previledges . When i ran create table separately I runs and creates table

When you use dynamic SQL inside stored procedure you execute it with rights of caller/invoker. I suspect that it is accout for reporting and has limited privileges.

Comment: I have the previledges . When i ran create table separately I runs and creates table

Comment: what should be the work aroud this any suggestions??